# Location not being fetched in android service

Tags: android, android-service, locationlistener

Hi all this is my service class which I use to get location even if am in background

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getName();
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = /*600000*/1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0;

public class BackgroundLocation implements LocationListener {

    private final String LOG_TAG = TrackingLocation.class.getName();

    Context context;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    public Location currentLocation;
    private Tracker tracker;
    long userId;
    long projectId;
    long savedTime;

    IProjectController iProjectController;
    HttpCookie authCookie;
    IAuthPref_ iAuthPref;
    RestAdapter adapter;

    AlertDialog gpsDisabledAlert;

    SlumviewPersistence persistence;

    public BackgroundLocation(final Context context, long userID, long projectID) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userId = userID;
        this.projectId = projectID;
        iAuthPref = new IAuthPref_(this.context);


        if (locationManager == null)
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            //return TODO;
        }

        if (isGpsEnabled()) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GPS");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 6000, 0, this);
            CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 10000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    if (currentLocation != null && currentLocation.getLatitude() != 0.00 && currentLocation.getLongitude() != 0.00) {

                    } else {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        locationManager.removeUpdates(BackgroundLocation.this);
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Switching");
                        switchToNP();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        } else {
            alertToEnableGPS();
        }


    }

    private void switchToNP() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 6000, 0, this);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NP");
    }

    public void alertToEnableGPS() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Your Device's GPS is Disable")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("GPS Error")
                .setPositiveButton("Gps On",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                context.startActivity(myIntent);
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        gpsDisabledAlert = builder.create();
        gpsDisabledAlert.show();
    }

    public Boolean isGpsEnabled() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure
                .isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (gpsStatus) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


        Log.i("GetLocation", "Location " + location + "    currtie: " + curTime + "    saved:  " + savedTime);
        if (curTime > savedTime + 10 * 60 * 1000) {   //this should hopefully cause the update interval to be 10 mins.

            if (location != null && location.getLatitude() != 0.0 && location.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
                currentLocation = location;



        }

    }

    private void showConnectionLossMessage() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry no connection available. Please try again after sometime", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");


    BackgroundLocation location = new BackgroundLocation(this, userid, projectid);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    /*if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }*/
}
}
```

Am using service for first time as well.
I think am missing out something important. Can anyone point out wat it is ??

Comment: Can you remove everything that is not related to location services

Comment: @TimCastelijns removed code as u said

Comment: Did the service is created ?

Comment: yes service is created i could logs from oncreate method